# How to pass components from array to route react-router-dom (typescript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, jsx

I try like that, it worked before. But now, when i try on new project, its not working. Error is "JSX element type 'Element' does not have any construct or call signatures."

App.tsx:

```
import { BrowserRouter, HashRouter, Route, Routes, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { routes } from './Routes/routes';

function App() {

  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
              {
                routes.map(({ path, element: Element }) =>
                  <Route key={path} path={path} element={<Element />}></Route>
                )
              }
              <Route path="*" element={<Navigate replace to="/cards" />} />
            </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Route array type:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';

export interface IRoute {
  path: string,
  element?: FC
}
```

Route array:

```
import CardList from "../components/pages/CardList";
import { IRoute } from "../models/IRoute";


export const routes: IRoute[] = [
  { path: '/cards', element: CardList },
];
```

[image]

error if used RouteObject type
[image: error if used RouteObject type]

Comment: I just set element in type as required, problem is solved ```export interface IRoute {
  path: string,
  element: FC
}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are *mostly* adhering to `react-router-dom`'s `Route` component API, I'd suggest importing `react-router-dom`'s [`RouteObject`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/lib/context.ts#L16-L54) type instead of redeclaring your own. This ensures correct typing.

```
import { RouteObject } from 'react-router-dom';
import CardList from "../components/pages/CardList";

export const routes: RouteObject[] = [
  { path: "/cards", element: <CardList /> },
];
```

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { routes } from './Routes/routes';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        {routes.map(({ path, element }) =>
          <Route key={path} path={path} element={element} />
        )}
        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate replace to="/cards" />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: Edit how-to-pass-components-from-array-to-route-react-router-dom-typescript]

You could simplify the rendering as well if you move all the routes (*i.e. the "catch-all" route*) to the routes configuration and use the [`useRoutes`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-routes) hook. It handles all the route "mapping" and rendering.

Example:

```
import { RouteObject } from 'react-router-dom';
import CardList from "../components/pages/CardList";

export const routes: RouteObject[] = [
  { path: "/cards", element: <CardList /> },
  ....
  { path: "*", element: <Navigate replace to="/cards" /> },
];
```

```
import { BrowserRouter, useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { routes } from './Routes/routes';

function App() {
  const appRoutes = useRoutes(routes);
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      {appRoutes}
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: Edit how-to-pass-components-from-array-to-route-react-router-dom-typescript (forked)]

The takeaway here is that you shouldn't reinvent the "wheel" RRD provides.

Comment: ```element: <CardList /> ``` for some reason doesnt work. Error is ```CardList' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof CardList'?```

Comment: @tanto39 Seems like there may've been a mixup, something trivial, in implementing this solution as it's working in the sandbox. If you like, could you create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo (*or fork mine and edit*) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: In the sandbox it works, but not in the Visual Studio Code, i am confused...

Comment: @tanto39 Codesandbox is basically a VSCode clone that runs in the browser. If you copy/paste your code into CSB it's running without issue?

Comment: now the error is in the sandbox too. I change your example in a sandbox [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-pass-components-from-array-to-route-react-router-dom-typescript-forked-sj74n9?file=/src/routes.ts). I attach the screenshot above

Comment: @tanto39 The error, or issue, I see in the sandbox is that you are trying to render JSX from a `.ts` file. Changing the file extension to `.tsx` the code renders without issue. Here's a [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-pass-components-from-array-to-route-react-router-dom-typescript-forked-o32uiw?file=/src/routes.ts) from the sandbox you linked.